# shelf life of kim chee

Tags: storage-lifetime, kimchi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does kimchi go bad?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/does-kimchi-go-bad)

I have some 'antique' kim chee in the back of the fridge. How can one tell if it is gone bad? Given that kim chee is fermented, it is hard to tell if it is no longer safe to eat or acceptable to offer to guests, say. Does aging improve the flavor? up to what point?

Comment: oops. I had searched for 'kim chee', not 'kimchi'. thanks for spotting the dupe!